# Input field focus boarder different behaviours in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Here is the issue, I have an input field, and I set:

```
outline: none !important;
```

In Chrome, when I type in some letters, it works fine. However, when I test it in Firefox, the purple focus border appears.

How to disable it?

Here is html file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    .input-large{

    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    letter-spacing: 35px;
    outline: none !important;
    font-family: Courier New !important;


    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <input class="input-large" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="5" size="5" autofocus>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: lets try it.. `-moz-outline:none;`

Comment: Tried this code, but it's still there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input {
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Make input box-shadow to none in mozilla firefox.
Try using this, It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

every `input` field has a `:invalid` property associated with it, by default its rendered as a Red outline/shadow in firefox.

to override this add the following code in your CSS

```
.input-large:invalid
    {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
    }
```

Regards

Shiva